# Where do I find the name for my data context?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this following code:

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(YourDataContextType), 
                             new ContextConfiguration() { 
                                 ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

I know what does into the "yourdatacontexttype" but I cannot seem to find where it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually the name of your .edmx file with 'Entities' appended, so if your edmx is called 'Foo' you're looking for `FooEntities`. This is of course under the assumption you use database first and have generated an .edmx from your db.

As found [here](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/07/using-entity-framework-code-first-ctp4.html), when you use Code First, you need the following:

Replace

```
typeof(Models.ProductCatalog)
```

with

```
() => new Models.{YourModel}(connectionString).ObjectContext
```

Comment: This is visual studio 2010.  would it still be an .edmx file?

Comment: I do not have any .edmx files in my solutions explorer.  This is a dynamic data web pages that is supposed to connect to one table in a database.

Comment: I got it. It was the name to the .dbml file followed by ContextType.  if you do not have a .dbml file you need to create one by right clicking on your project in solutions Add new item --> then Linq to SQL Database.  That will produce a .dbml file.  By default this is called dataClasses1.dbml  Thanks again.

Comment: @user1485631 If you have a dbml you are using LinqToSql not EntityFramework.